# Web Crawling Content Tag Issue

Tags: c#

I am writing a web crawler that goes to a particular website, read its Data and take it back as a response.

I've been successful in bringing response from certain pages but i am stuck with one page that says

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame.

The error comes in visual studio frame. The link works fine in Browsers. I've done some research and found that the page I've crawled doesn't have `" CONTENT="allow" "` tag in html. Since i can not change the html... is there any way i can over pass the problem???

Comment: Sounds like a *Framekiller*? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller). Can you post the URL of the website sothat we can have a look at the HTML?

Comment: https://providers.metroplus.org/providers/Pages/Member-Eligibility.aspx

Comment: That is a secure page... you need to find a way of showing us the html for the page once logged in.

Comment: i can give u the pwd n user name??

Comment: @Muhammadbilal-ur-rehman Do not offer to give any usernames or passwords to anyone via this site. Post the HTML above in your question - you need to be able to [post a minimal and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: are you trying to make a windows application to crawl the website through a webbrowser control ?

Comment: yes.... I am  indeed